# What is attr(,"scaled:center") and attr(,"scaled:scale") in the scale() function in R?

Tags: r

I ran the code:

```
r_df_scaled <- as.matrix(scale(r_df[,c(-1,-2)]))
```

The result was a matrix with standard normal distribution and the below:

```
 attr(,"scaled:center")
           Fresh             Milk          Grocery           Frozen 
       10639.957         4780.110         6899.267         2484.594 
Detergents_Paper       Delicassen 
        2229.187         1192.970 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
           Fresh             Milk          Grocery           Frozen 
       8630.3470        3800.6264        5844.9457        2359.4800 
Detergents_Paper       Delicassen 
       2581.6316         923.4373
```

Can you explain what `scaled:center`, `scaled:scale` refers to?

Comment: read details section of scale man page: `?scale`

Comment: '?scale' says 
[center : 
either a logical value or a numeric vector of length equal to the number of columns of x.
scale :
either a logical value or a numeric vector of length equal to the number of columns of x.]
i didnt get anything still

Comment: scale function is used to get zscore of a variable. You know what is zscore?

Comment: m..maybe? what i can know is i should study more thx XD

Comment: zscore is related to normal distribution. It is a measure that explains how many standard deviation is a given value is away from the center (which is mean).

Comment: Did you watch that video? and try this exercise from that video: `scale(65, center = 81, scale = 6.3)`. value = 65, mean = 81 and standard deviation = 6.3

Comment: The relevant bits of the help are :"*If center is TRUE then centering is done by subtracting the column means*" (although you can manually enter the scale), and "*If scale is TRUE then scaling is done by dividing the (centered) columns of x by their standard deviations*" . So the attributes return the means, and standard deviations in your example.  ( so in your example it scales your variable to mean zero , and variance one) [your variables do not need to be normally distributed to apply this transform, and the transform does not make them normally distributed. either]

Comment: how nice answers! by the way why didnt you guys put up the answer? i cant adopt anything

Answer (score 2):

`scaled:center` find the **mean** of the rows(or column, depend on where the comma is)

for example, dataframe 'test':

```
   cola colb colc
    1    2    1
    4    3    2
    4    1    3
```

for cola, the mean is (1+4+4)/3=3

for colb, the mean is (3+2+1)/3=2

for colc, the mean is (1+2+3)/3=2

so see the printed message after running scale function for rows in 'test'

```
           cola colb colc
[1,] -1.1547005    0   -1
[2,]  0.5773503    1    0
[3,]  0.5773503   -1    1
attr(,"scaled:center")
cola colb colc 
   3    2    2 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
    cola     colb     colc 
1.732051 1.000000 1.000000
```

Did you see the `attr(,"scaled:center")` ? The same to the mean we counted

`scaled:scale` shows the **standard deviation** in that row/column

```
> sd(test$cola)
[1] 1.732051
> sd(test$colb)
[1] 1
> sd(test$colc)
[1] 1
```

the same to `attr(,"scaled:scale")`